# Package import org.apache.storm.hbase.* does not exist

Tags: maven, hadoop, hbase, apache-storm

I want to store some data from Apache Storm into Hbase. I have inserted all dependencies that I found necessary. but still I have some problem with:

> package import org.apache.storm.hbase.* does not exist

My POM.xml is like this:

```
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Storm library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Storm-Kafka integration library -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-hbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>3.3</version>

            <configuration>

                <source>1.8</source>

                <target>1.8</target>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>


        <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.sf</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.dsa</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.rsa</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.EC</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.ec</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <!--Note - the version would be inherited-->
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>/usr/local/storm/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


    </plugins>



</build>
```

Is there anything else I need to add as a dependency in my POM?
please help me, I spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: Why do you have a plugin set up to copy dependencies to Storm's lib directory? Your Shade plugin configuration looks fine to me, when you build your jar, you should get two of them in your build target directory. Make sure you use the one that has all the dependencies bundled. Open the jar as a zip file, and check that there's an "org/apache/storm/hbase" directory in there.

Comment: Your dependencies unfortunately are all over the place (why do you need Kafka or any `hadoop-*` thing other than `hadoop-client`?). What are you actually trying to do? Can you share your code?